# MySql self join sub inner join returning cross join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table called employeee (triple e's):

```
+------------+------------+---------------+--------------+
| employeeid | lastname   | country       | departmentid |
+------------+------------+---------------+--------------+
|        123 | Rafferty   | Australia     |           31 |
|        124 | Jones      | Australia     |           33 |
|        145 | Heisenberg | Australia     |           33 |
|        201 | Robinson   | United States |           34 |
|        305 | Smith      | Germany       |           34 |
|        306 | Williams   | Germany       |         NULL |
+------------+------------+---------------+--------------+
```

My intention was to pair up (self join) people within the same country and put them side by side.

So I came up with the following query with some help from a colleague:

```
SELECT f.employeeid, f.lastname, s.employeeid, s.lastname, f.country
FROM employeee f INNER JOIN employeee s ON f.country = s.country
```

The result was not 100% as I intended. A cross join seems to be in the result:

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+---------------+
| employeeid | lastname   | employeeid | lastname   | country       |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+---------------+
|        123 | Rafferty   |        123 | Rafferty   | Australia     |
|        124 | Jones      |        123 | Rafferty   | Australia     |
|        145 | Heisenberg |        123 | Rafferty   | Australia     |
|        123 | Rafferty   |        124 | Jones      | Australia     |
|        124 | Jones      |        124 | Jones      | Australia     |
|        145 | Heisenberg |        124 | Jones      | Australia     |
|        123 | Rafferty   |        145 | Heisenberg | Australia     |
|        124 | Jones      |        145 | Heisenberg | Australia     |
|        145 | Heisenberg |        145 | Heisenberg | Australia     |
|        201 | Robinson   |        201 | Robinson   | United States |
|        305 | Smith      |        305 | Smith      | Germany       |
|        306 | Williams   |        305 | Smith      | Germany       |
|        305 | Smith      |        306 | Williams   | Germany       |
|        306 | Williams   |        306 | Williams   | Germany       |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+---------------+
```

Also why is there no use of the `AS` alias keyword when doing `f.employeeid, s.employeeid`? I thought these were required.

Comment: What results do you want?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My intention was to pair up (self join) people within the same country and put them side by side.

Comment: @RobertRocha . . . And that looks like what your result set is doing.  You have accomplished your intention.

Comment: It's not quite a complete cross join. For example, note that there's no Rafferty/Robinson pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want unique pairs of people within a country and you want to avoid pairing people up with themselves, then add the following condition to your query

```
WHERE f.employeeid < s.employeeid
```

Comment: Thanks that was what I was looking for

Comment: I am curious why is it `<` less than? I am not understanding the reasoning behind that.

Comment: @RobertRocha `>` also works. As you mentioned, your result is a cross join within a country, which means every possible combination of id's within a country is produced i.e. if you only had values 1 and 2 you would get (1,1) (1,2) (2,1) and (2,2). By specifying either `>` or `<` you would limit your results to either (1,2) or (2,1)